# how to load iframe along side to the website using java script?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Hi the below is the content script code which will load the 'my page' through iframe on every tab i open on the browser.

Ex: Suppose if open amazon, on left side of amazon.in iframe will be loaded. I wanted this iframe to be loaded along side to the website. But here it is loaded on the page content, so some of elements are not accessible.

CODE:

```
var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;
if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
// Must be declared at web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('frame.html');

// Some styles for a fancy sidebar
iframe.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:0;left:0;display:block;' +
                       'width:300px;height:100%;z-index:1000;';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Below image is the present view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVFr6.png)

Comment: You'll have to modify the site's style e.g. `document.body.style.cssText = 'max-width: calc(100% - 300px) !important`. I think there should be existing answers about this technique's details and specifics, try searching.

Comment: by reducing max width , it is just reducing the page 300px less but it is not separating the iframe and page. I wanted it like two pages of opened book. One page(iframe ) and other is amazon

Comment: Well, you'll need to shift the page as well by setting `margin-left:300px !important`.